# Elements added with innerHtml not affected by Javascript library

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I've included a stripped down version of my code. I have a function which generates list elements, and the elements have children which should have a 3D effect from a library I've included. As is, the library is not affecting the elements generated, I assume because it is set by innerHtml or finishes generating after the script at the end is read. Is there a way to make this work?

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
  function createList() {
    const list = ["https://placekitten.com/300/300", "https://placekitten.com/300/300"];
    var output = '<ul>';
    list.forEach((example) => {
      output +=
      `
      <li>
        <div class="img-container" data-tilt>
          <img src="${example}" />
        </div>
      </li>
      `;
    });

    output += '</ul>';
    document.getElementById("catalog-container").innerHTML = output;

  }
</script>

<body onload="createList()">
  <div id="catalog-container">
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="vanilla-tilt.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See [the documentation](https://micku7zu.github.io/vanilla-tilt.js/) (scroll down to the _"JS Way"_ title)

Answer (score 0):

Create the elements before the library script runs. There are several options. One is to put your script tag before the library's, and avoid the `body onload` handler:

```
<body>
    <div id="catalog-container">
    </div>
    <script>
        function createList() {
            // ...
        }
        createList(); // or remove the function entirely
    </script>
    <script src="vanilla-tilt.js"></script>
```

Another is to, instead, dynamically inject the library after your script runs. At the end of your function:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'vanilla-tilt.js';
```

Or [call the library on your new elements manually](https://micku7zu.github.io/vanilla-tilt.js/).